# Unix file manipulation (IF match, AND (>= x and <y)) then this, else NA

Tags: unix, csv

I have 2 tab-delimited files - with differing column & row numbers in each.

Please note: some of the 'names' in column 1 (in each file) are repeated a varying number of times. Each of the real files are millions of rows each.

File 1:

```
Sc1 10  20
Sc1 20  30
Sc1 30  40
Sc2 40  50
Sc2 50  60
Sc2 60  70
Sc3 70  80
Sc3 80  90
Sc3 90  100
```

File 2:

```
Sc1 22  23  100
Sc1 44  45  50
Sc2 60  61  25
Sc3 79  80  40
Sc3 100 101 40
```

I would like to test the following:

IF the value in the first column & first row of File2 matches the value anywhere in the first column of File1, AND IF the second column & first row value of File2 is >= to the second column File1 but < the third column File1 (these would be on the corresponding row of File1 after the match established in the first 'IF'), THEN write the value from column 4 row 1 File2 to File3, ELSE write NA to File3.

After testing for every File2 column 1 values, File3 should look like the following:

```
100
NA
25
40
NA
```

I am hoping I have made that clear, and that someone can kindly provide some assistance :)

Many thanks

Ted (Completely new to unix and learning everyday)

#

Edit
I can achieve this within Excel:

Paste File 1 from cells A1:C9

Paste File 2 from cells D1:G5

In H1 write the following formula:

=IF(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$9,D1, $B$1:$B$9,"<="&E1,$C$1:$C$9,">"&E1)>0,G1,"NA")

Copy formula down to H5.

But – the real world files exceed the size of Excel, so transferring this to Unix is my problem.

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Comment: Do you care how this is solved?  For example, it seems like the merge facility of the `sort` program can do it with careful attention to the key specifications.

Comment: Being completely new to unix command line, I often don't know where to start or how to source the right answer........ I was stuck and I'm sorry if asking has offended you :(  I will see what I can do with merge / sort. Do I care how this is solved? Of course I do, that's why I'm asking, which will help me learn more.

Comment: Apologies, I actually have no idea where to start - extremely new to unix coding. It is beyond anything I have already been doing with text file manipulation.

Comment: I've tried combining the 2 files into a single tab-delimited file and then running an awk command: (awk '{if ($4=$1 && $5>=$2 && $5<$3) {print $7}}' file3.txt > file4.txt) but this only tests within each row. I feel like using awk with NR==FNR 'might' help. But I'm still looking for a friendly person to help / point me in the right direction.